# многопоточный обход массива\строки средствами php

Tags: php, многопоточность

Допустим есть строка, которая состоит из символов в кол-ве от 400 до 800 тысяч штук и длина которой кратна четному числу. Мы ее превращаем в массив:

```
$string = str_split('1234567890.......');
```

и делим на, допустим, 8 кусков, создавая массив из 8 строк;

```
$combine = array_chunk($string,8);
```

После чего с каждой переменной данного массива, посимвольно, работает некоторая функция и потом результат работы собирается обратно в обновленную строку $string.

Вопрос - есть ли корректный способ сделать так, чтобы каждый экземпляр массива $combine обрабатывался функцией параллельно, а не ждал пока будет его очередь при линейном обходе средствами foreach?

У меня сервер на windows, с апачем и php 7.4\8.2, php подгружается как модуль для Apache. Читал что при подобном варианте возможно только использовать proc_open для многопоточного серверного вычисления, но не совсем понимаю как это можно реализовать. Может есть какие-то рабочие примеры? Не очень хочется городить кривой велосипед из multicurl с обращениями самой страницы к себе и выдергиваниями фрагментов кода, т.к. это явно все будет работать через 3 палки и криво. Нужно что-то кроме shell_exec, т.к. при работе с ним возможны ошибки, если страница закрывается раньше чем завершается работа консольного cli интерфейса.

На данный момент обход всей строки обычным способом занимает около 37 секунд, что крайне много и есть сильное желание сократить как-то это значение.

**UPD**

Основное время затрачивается именно на линейный обход строки в массиве и преобразование данных в ней же. Поэтому рассматривается вариант параллельной обработки нескольких переменных массива одновременно.

Comment: В целом пхп не многопоточен, хотя есть модули. Чего вы там делаете внутри той функции, мб достаточно будет ее оптимизации.

Comment: Вот свежая статья как раз по удобному использованию  proc_open  https://habr.com/ru/articles/756642/

Comment: пробовали сплит и чанк заменить на `strl_len + substr` ? и вообще надо ли там именно массив делать?

Comment: @teran очевидно что это мелочь, которая в лучшем случае занимает долю процента от этих 37 секунд

Comment: @Ипатьев сами вызовы функций - да. А вот что он с результатом дальше делает - большой вопрос.

Comment: @teran выполняются побитовые сдвиги по каждому символу, сама по себе строка - это сугубо поток бинарных данных.

Comment: Побитовые сдвиги быстро делаются, мне кажется вы больше потеряете на организации многопоточности, чем выиграете.

Comment: @CrazyElf увы, в данном случае это специфика проекта и таковы требования. Поэтому и есть идея чтобы полученную строку аккауратно разрезать по нужному шаблону и запустить параллельно несколько преобразований, а по окончаниию всех - собрать строку обратно вместе.

Comment: а сам алгоритм преобразования строк секретный, его нельзя в целом опубликовать, чтобы посмотреть и воспроизвести? Просто пройти по массиву и сдвинуть биты не должно занимать 37сек.

Comment: там если что еще есть `pack/unpack` методы для распаковки бинарных строк.

Comment: @teran нет, нельзя. Речь в вопросе не о механизме распаковки, а о том как распараллелить его на несколько идентичных потоков.

Comment: тогда статья из комментария №2 весьма доступно это объясняет.

Comment: Можете попробовать взять [OpenSwoole](https://openswoole.com/) и использовать его асинхронные [инструменты](https://openswoole.com/docs/modules/swoole-process). Также можно разделить обработку (как и уже сказано раньше) в разные процессы и установить process affinity на разные CPU ядра, чтобы они не пересекались с друг другом, так как в другом случае будет тратится больше времени на переключение контекста.

Comment: Попробуйте через [мультизапрос curl](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-exec.php), либо запускать скрипт с нужными данными. [Статья по теме](https://habr.com/ru/articles/448464/), документация по [passthru](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.passthru.php)